# How to delete specific data mongodb + nodejs + expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, node-mongodb-native

How to remove data using node+express. Here is my router for delete process

```
// Delete user
router.get('/deleteuser/:id', function(req, res) { 
var db = req.db;

var uid = req.params.id;
db.collection('usercollection').remove(uid, function(err, result) { 
    res.send( (result === 1) ? { msg: '' } : { msg: 'error: '+ err } );
});

});
```

from the above function, i got 404 error page.

```
Error: Not Found
at Layer.app.use.res.render.message [as handle] (/media/bcd44b6a-9c2e-4496-81da-b45d3c349c91/mywork/nodejs/blog/blogone/app.js:40:15)
at trim_prefix (/media/bcd44b6a-9c2e-4496-81da-b45d3c349c91/mywork/nodejs/blog/blogone/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:240:15)
at /media/bcd44b6a-9c2e-4496-81da-b45d3c349c91/mywork/nodejs/blog/blogone/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:208:9
at Function.proto.process_params (/media/bcd44b6a-9c2e-4496-81da-b45d3c349c91/mywork/nodejs/blog/blogone/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:269:12)
at next (/media/bcd44b6a-9c2e-4496-81da-b45d3c349c91/mywork/nodejs/blog/blogone/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:199:19)
at next (/media/bcd44b6a-9c2e-4496-81da-b45d3c349c91/mywork/nodejs/blog/blogone/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:176:38)
at /media/bcd44b6a-9c2e-4496-81da-b45d3c349c91/mywork/nodejs/blog/blogone/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:137:5
at /media/bcd44b6a-9c2e-4496-81da-b45d3c349c91/mywork/nodejs/blog/blogone/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:250:10
at next (/media/bcd44b6a-9c2e-4496-81da-b45d3c349c91/mywork/nodejs/blog/blogone/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:160:14)
at next_layer (/media/bcd44b6a-9c2e-4496-81da-b45d3c349c91/mywork/nodejs/blog/blogone/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:77:14)
```

What's wrong with my router code.. please help me. i'm new to node & express

Answer (score 3, accepted):

finally i solved the problem here is my code:

```
    // Delete user
    router.get('/deleteuser/:id', function(req, res) { 

    var db = req.db;

    var uid = req.params.id.toString();
    var collection = db.get('usercollection');

    collection.remove({"_id":uid}, function(err, result) { 
        res.send( (result === 1) ? { msg: 'Deleted' } : { msg: 'error: '+ err } );
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

in the:

```
db.collection('usercollection').remove({"_id":uid},function(err,result){
    ...
});
```

try this

Comment: i tried the above code. it returned an error Object #<Manager> has no method 'collection'.